# Problems with Java JRun Cache

Tags: java, coldfusion, jboss, war, jrun

Jrun4 came bundled with our install of Coldfusion. Recently we decided to create a new server within JRun to accomodate a new webapp that will always need to be run over SSL.

Long story short. The app was deployed when a bug was found and quickly fixed, recompiled and we redeployed the webapp. As far as JRun is showing the new webapp gets deployed and is being served however, when hitting the webapp none of the new changes are being served up. To verify that the changes are indeed present, I have actually verified the checksum differences and also run a java decompiler on the modified class files and the changes are present. I have added console messages to the app to verify that they get printed to console, none of the new messages appear.

The procedures I have attempted:

1. Hot deployed the war file, console stated the file was redeployed
2. Turned off the JRun server hosting the file and restarted it with the modified file.
3. Completely deleted the existing JRun server hosting the webapp. Shutdown JRun. Restarted and created a new JRun server to host the webapp.
4. Opened javacpl.exe, Java Control Panel, and deleted all temporary files, applets and applications included.
5. Downloaded TOMCAT and deployed the same war to the webapps directory, everything showed up correctly. I cannot use tomcat though as the company would need to allow it to be used.

I am now at the point that I think I may need to reimage the entire server and deploy the webapp on a fresh JRun install however, there really must be a better way.

Comment: sure it's not your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an older version of the `war` being programmatically added to the java `classpath` that *jrun* was using.

This was causing it to reference classes from the classpath rather then the newer deployed classes.